# Blender 2.8 layer grid/palette not showing up in 3D view

Tags: layers

Where is the layers grid? Mine seems to have vanished in the Blender 2.8 beta. on Mac OSX

I tried numpad/ or Object Mode, View, View Global/Local 
but made no difference.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the layers panel in the 3D view header from 2.7 and prior?

Answer (score 2):

There is no **Layer** grid in 2.80. It's replaced by **Collection** system.

Read here about this change: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Layers

[image: collection]